# How to new a class with args in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

```
public class Test{
    public void Test(String name){};
    public static void main()
    {
        Test t=new Test("right");
    }
}
```

There is error in the above code when compile, could anyone tell me how to use the construct function with arg in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no constructor with parameters:

```
public void Test(String name){}; //method with Test name
public Test(String name){}; //constructor
```

Answer (score 3):

Correct version is as below

```
public class Test{
    public Test(String name){};
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        Test t=new Test("right");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Constructors do not have a return type.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) Change

```
public void Test(String name){};
```

to

```
public Test(String name){};
```

Answer (score 3):

`public static void main()` should be `public static void main(String[] somethingulike)`
It is the default that you should follow

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was in how you defined the constructor.  Constructors don't have return types.

```
public class Test{
    public Test(String name){};
    public static void main()
    {
        Test t=new Test("right");
    }
}
```

Other than that, you're getting it!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test{
    private String name;
    public Test(String name){ this.name = name; };
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        for (String arg : args) {
            Test t=new Test(arg);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are also `methods` which do not have a `return` type (void or other return types). Since you defined similar to constructor but with a return type the compiler thinks it as a method and it will not complain for that, but when you are trying to instantiate the class with an argument constructor it failed because it was not able to find a constructor of that type. If there is no explicit constructor defined, java compiler will autormatically use the default constructor which is the no argument constructor. Also your main method should have the `String[] args` as parameter.